# C++ CMake undefined reference linking error

Tags: c++, cmake

I am new in CMake and I am trying to build my game I made on windows with Visual Studio now in Ubuntu with Clion and Cmake. In CMakeLists SFML library works fine. I have tested it on the other project but I think the problem is in linking my object files. Although, I included and added executable I don't know how to properly link all the files.

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.14 )
set( PROJECT_NAME RPG  )

project( ${PROJECT_NAME} )

set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug )


set(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR "/home/michal/Libraries/SFML-2.5.1/include")
set(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR "/home/michal/Libraries/SFML-2.5.1/lib")
set(SFML_DIR "/home/michal/Libraries/SFML-2.5.1/lib/cmake/SFML")

find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS system window graphics network audio)

set(SOURCES
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Main.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Application.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Animation.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Blocked.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Character.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/CollisionHandler.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Create.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Delete.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Dialogues.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Dragon.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Draw.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Enemy.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/EnemySpawner.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Fight.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/File.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Game.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/HUD.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Input.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Interaction.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Inventory.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Item.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ItemFactory.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/LevelManager.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Map.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Mark.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Menu.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Mission.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Missions.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Movement.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Node.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Npc.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Obstacle.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/PathFinding.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Player.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Projectile.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Random.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Rect.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Shoot.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Skeleton.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/SkeletonBerserker.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Sprite.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/StatusBar.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Text.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Tile.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/TimeHandler.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Update.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Wrapper.cpp
        )

include_directories("/home/michal/repos/RPG/include" SFML_INCLUDE_DIR)

link_directories(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR)

add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries ( ${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)
```

Project's directory:
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwbJe.png)

Errors:

```
[  2%] Linking CXX executable RPG
CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/src/Dragon.cpp.o: In function `Dragon::~Dragon()':
/home/michal/repos/RPG/include/Dragon.h:4: undefined reference to `Enemy::~Enemy()'
CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/src/Enemy.cpp.o: In function `Enemy::Enemy(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int, int, int, float, float)':
/home/michal/repos/RPG/src/Enemy.cpp:4: undefined reference to `Character::~Character()'
CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/src/Game.cpp.o: In function `Player::Player(Player const&)':
/home/michal/repos/RPG/include/Player.h:6: undefined reference to `Character::~Character()'
CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/src/Game.cpp.o: In function `Npc::Npc(Npc const&)':
/home/michal/repos/RPG/include/Npc.h:6: undefined reference to `Character::~Character()'
CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/src/Npc.cpp.o: In function `Npc::Npc(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
/home/michal/repos/RPG/src/Npc.cpp:4: undefined reference to `Character::~Character()'
CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/src/Npc.cpp.o: In function `Npc::~Npc()':
/home/michal/repos/RPG/src/Npc.cpp:9: undefined reference to `Character::~Character()'
CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/src/Player.cpp.o:/home/michal/repos/RPG/src/Player.cpp:6: more undefined references to `Character::~Character()' follow
CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/src/Skeleton.cpp.o: In function `Skeleton::~Skeleton()':
/home/michal/repos/RPG/src/Skeleton.cpp:8: undefined reference to `Enemy::~Enemy()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/build.make:776: recipe for target 'RPG' failed
make[3]: *** [RPG] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/RPG.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'RPG' failed
make: *** [RPG] Error 2
```

Comment: So show us the code where you have declared and defined `Enemy::~Enemy()` (for instance). I presume that's in the file Enemy.cpp. I know it's labouring the obvious, but the first thing to check is that you actually have defined the things that the linker is telling you are undefined.

Comment: I notice all the undefined items are destructors. Are you sure you haven't just forgotten to define the destructors, or that you have declared them when you didn't need to?

Comment: Exactly as @john said, maybe you declared the destructors (preventing the compiler from generating default ones), but did not implement them?

Comment: It turned out that I have undefined pure virtual destructor in Character class, I made in empty and also I have undefined pure virtual destructor in Enemy class. However i can't define it empty because if I do there is a "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)". The inheritance structure is: Character (pure virtual destructor) -> Enemy (pure virtual destructor)->Dragon,Skeleton... I am wondering how it was working in Windows. For this moment I don't know what to do about pure virtual Enemy destructor. I dont have any other destructors declared in headers.

Comment: @john I don't how to define Enemy::~Enemy() without errors

Comment: @michalovsky Of course the SIGSEQV problem could be a completely different bug. It's normal for bugs to show up on one system and not on another. So it's no surprise that you didn't see that problem on Windows. You just have to tackle it like you would any other bug.

Comment: SIGSEQV was about unitialized pointers, works fine, than you guys :)